# Optimal number of workers for small business model

Tags: modeling, optimization

I'm new here. I formed an analytical model of a small scale business where the expense can be defined as $C_L=(1-T).(1-1/n)$ and production rate can be defined as $R=1/(1-T+T/n)$.

Where $4<n<200$ is the number of workers and $0<T<1$ is the team work factor.

As we can see here, The expense will be higher for bigger values of $n$ and production rate will go down for smaller values of $n$.

Could anyone please help me to find the best number of workers which will give me the best production rate for minimum expense.

Comment: Are $R$ and $C$ measured in the same units and you wish to maximise $R-C$, by choosing $n$ subject to the constraint?

Comment: Just do it manually on a spreadsheet (excel, open office, Google sheets)  rows for n and cols for different values of T.

Comment: This certainly looks like homework to me. Just compute $\frac{d\big(\alpha_1 C_L + \alpha_2 R\big)}{dn}$.

Comment: @CloseToc, R and C both are measured in different units. So I can't subtract them.

Comment: @seanv507, When we propose a model, It should work for all values of T within a specific range. Manually you can't do it.

Comment: @Marc Claesen, you can't find a maximum for those given functions.Minimum will give you the least number of worker which will hurt the production rate. I'm looking for the best trade-off strategies we can establish mathematically/statistically.

Comment: If you are looking for the best-trade off strategy, you need to specify the trade-off. If $C$ and $R$ are measured in different units you need a function that brings them to the same units. That function should represent the firm's objectives/interests/values. If you have such a function, you can problably (depending on the function) solve this problem analytically using the Kuhn-Tucker procedure. In the absence of such a function, you don't have an optimisation problem. 
C is presumably measured in dollars. You just need to relate the production rate to revenue.